# vertical-alignment in relative table-cell

Tags: html, css, cell, vertical-alignment, html-table

I want to vertically center the second td-element containing the "actualrow" without changing the height of the table.

I have already tried a lot of methods to vertically align my td-element and I hope you may help me with this problem. I had to cut the code otherwise it would be too large so I hope the code posted below is sufficient.

```php
echo '<table cellspacing="5%" cellpadding="14%" width="37.5%" rules="rows" border="1"   class="datatable" style="position:absolute;table-layout:fixed;left:12.42%;top:27%;border-right-width:6px;border-color:black">';
.
.
.

echo "<tr class='even'>";
$actualrow = $row['wav_nr'];
echo '<td nowrap border="0" align="left" valign="middle" style="position: relative;vertical-align: middle;">&nbsp;Wave ' . $actualrow . '</td>';

echo '<td nowrap align="center" valign="middle" style="position: relative;vertical-align: middle">' . (($actualrow * 10) - 9) . ' - ' . ($actualrow * 10) . '<br/>' . $moved_athletes . '</td>';
echo '<td nowrap align="center" valign="middle" style="vertical-align: middle;">' . date_create($row['wav_time'])->format('H:i') . '</td>';
echo '</tr>';
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might want to try this in the style attribute in the first line:

```
text-align: center;
```

this might help some or you could surround that tag with:

```
<center></center>
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you for the few hints!
I fixed it by giving the <tr> a "height:65px" style Attribute.
Also i removed the html alignments and added text-align:center to the <td> tags.
It just works!

Answer (score 0):

I think you want the following:

```
 echo '<td nowrap border="0" align="left" valign="middle" style="position: relative;vertical-align: top;">&nbsp;Wave ' . $actualrow . '</td>';
```

Change the value for `vertical-align` from `middle` to `top`.

Unless you are supporting very old browsers, you may omit `align` and `valign`.